# Spring MVC application under Fuse ESB

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, fuseesb

i've created simple Spring MVC application from SpringSource Tool template.

It works greate on Tomcat, but i wanted to move this application to Fuse ESB.

I copied my war file do deploy folder.

I've looked in karaf, and it shows me, that application is started.

Next i looked in logs and i sow:

> Fri Dec 09 2011 15:54:56 GMT+0100 (CET)   WARN    Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundle://241.0:1/com/ptest/app/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system

where com/ptest/app is my package - com.ptest.app

Karaf shows me, that application is runing, but when i try to open my application, page with 404 shows.

In logs i see, that url is not mapping.

Can i run MVC application under Fuse ESB ?